# Toggle isKinematic on Rigidbody re-triggers collision

Tags: unity

Apparently since 2019 you cannot toggle isKinematic without re-triggering the collision. How am I now supposed to push back NavMesh Agents?

It used to be you could disable agent, set kinematic to false, puch back, reset. Now I cannot do that anymore since when I set isKinematic to false, the collision is triggered again, calling the same logic.

i.e if you want to knockback an agent when it collides with a swords hitbox, you need to disable kinematic before you apply the force. And since you do that the same frame you get hit, it will re-trigger the collision.

Comment: Have you tried using Physics.IgnoreCollision to prevent the collider pair from generating a new collision for the frames when you don't want it to happen?

Comment: I tried that but I need the colliders to be able to hit each other while the enemy is being pushed back in case the player decides to swing the sword again.

Comment: I wouldn't implement this feature with forces at all. Just keep the agents kinematic at all times and use MovePosition to drive the motion for the knockback. This makes it easier to fine-tune the motion you want, and doesn't interfere with your usual collision handling.

Comment: @DMGregory that’s true but then they will not respect my walls so if I hit an enemy that’s up against a wall it will just be pushed thru the wall. Where a dynamic body would react properly.

Comment: That's what shapecasts are for.

Comment: True I guess in my case a raycast would be enough since everything is flat. Ill give it a try :)